# bower EINVEND Decomposed endpoint must have a name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have error in my attempt to init bower.json, Please help, I'm a beginner

user@ubuntu:/var/www/test/current$ *bower install bower*
 ENOENT No bower.json present

user@ubuntu:/var/www/test/current$ *bower init bower*
ENOINT Register requires an interactive shell
Additional error details: Note that you can manually force an interactive          shell with --config.interactive

user@ubuntu:/var/www/test/current$ *bower init --config.interactive*
? name test_pro                                                                                                                                                  ? description desc
? main file index.html
? what types of modules does this package expose?
? keywords
? authors Admin
? license MIT
? homepage
? set currently installed components as dependencies? Yes
? add commonly ignored files to ignore list? Yes
? would you like to mark this package as private which prevents it from   being accidentally published to the registry? Yes

**bower EINVEND Decomposed endpoint must have a name**

Answer (score 2):

You probably already did a bower install and the *bower_components* map is preventing a succesful init.

Try deleting the *bower_components* folder and run **bower init** once more. The error should be gone and the bower.json file should be initialised correctly.